# Check for Agent Copies in Wait Blocks then Free them

Tags: anylogic

I am modeling an development process where projects (Epics) come from the Source and are broken down into their components (Features) that go through development. Once those components (Features) are completed the project (Epic) is complete. Here are the model detail (see screen shot too). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRihf.jpg)

1. Epics agents (main project) leave the source and are copied with a random number of copies by the Split block into Features agents (the components of the main project).
2. Epics agent is linked bi-directionally with Feature agent. At "On exit copy" the connection is made with "agent.ConnectTo(original)".
3. The Feature agents then move to one of 2 Service block for development based in the probability set in a SelectOutput.
4. The Epic moves immediately to a Wait (epicWait) and will remain there until all the copied agents (Feature) have moved through their development Service blocks.
5. When an Feature leaves the development Service it goes to a Wait block (featureWait1 or 2) where it needs to check to see if all the Feature agents that went to the other development block are complete. If so the Feature agent should free itself, the other Feature agents in the other featureWait, and the matching Epic agent that is waiting in the epicWait. This signifies the project (Epic) is complete.

So my questions are how do I write the On Enter function to check the other featureWait block for other linked Feature agents? And then how do I free them to signify the epic is now complete? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

What I would do instead of using featureWait1 and 2, on the sinkFeature1 and 2 I would do

```
if(agent.EpicLink.getConnectedAgent().featureLink.getConnectionsNumber()==1){
    epicWait.free(agent.EpicLink.getConnectedAgent());
}
agent.EpicLink.disconnect();
```

where epicLink represents the connection in the feature agent that is the connection to the associated epic

Comment: Thanks Felipe that is a great idea. The connection is named epicLink so I just used your code in the on enter for the feature sinks with a lower case e in epicLink.  I get the error though: " The method getConnectedAgent(int) in the type LinkToAgentCollection<Epic,Feature> is not applicable for the arguments ()" … Also there is window by the on enter code that shows the error and another that says "Use self, agent". Any ideas?

Comment: because epicLink should be a single connection, not a collection... change that in the properties of your link to agents obejct

Comment: OK thanks Felipe. I fixed that but now its giving me the error that disconnectFromAll() and getConnectionsNumber() are undefined for type LinkToAgent. It seems like these part of the LinkToAgentCollections interface....

Comment: change it with agent.EpicLink.disconnect();

Comment: sorry... I updated the code, it was wrong... please be careful if i made mistakes you need to be able to use this code as a guide because i didn't test it myself since i don't have your model

Comment: OK I have it now and see that featureLink should be a collection of links while epicLink should be single. The model builds correctly but on running it once a feature enters sinkFeature2 it throws an error NullPointer exception. I am wondering if the link isn't being created when after the copies are created at the Split and the null error is because the epic agent waiting in epicWait is not actually connected to the copied feature agent going into the sink. to I am creating the link on the On exit copy of the Split with agent.connectTo(original) . Is that incorrect?

Comment: that means that Epiclink is not connected to anything probably

Comment: I am using agent.connectTo(original) at On exit copy of the split. Any reason why that would not connect the original with the copy?

Comment: agent.epicLink.connectTo(original)

Comment: Thanks so much Felipe. I fail to understand why AnyLogic is the way it is in some regards.... Why would it not have thrown an error if it was incorrect? Anyway, thanks so much for your help and patience. I am closing the question

Comment: because it's not incorrect.. it's just another type of connection

Comment: I see Felipe. I will give that some study. Thanks so much.